# Javascript while loop with if/else statements

Tags: javascript

Im trying to make this program display "Output" when the "value" is NOT 3, but it will display "Output3" if the value IS 3. But somehow this does not work. Please help.

```js
function changeText() {

  var x = 1;
  var value = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  var finalx = " ";

  while (x <= value) {

    if (x = 3) {
      finalx += "Output" + x + " ";

    } else {
      finalx += "Output";

    }
    x++;
  }

  output.innerHTML = finalx;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"> Your Output will be displayed here </div>
<br>
<br>

<input type="text" id="userInput" />
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" id="box" value="Click me" onclick="changeText();" />
```

Comment: There is no sense in using a while loop there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `x=3` to `x===3` to make comparison

Answer (score 5):

```
if (x = 3)
```

Actually, you assign 3 to x and always return true (not zero). What you need is

```
if (x === 3)
```

And you don’t really need the loop here. Just need to check on value

```
if (value == 3)
```

Comment: He should also remove the while loop like @lilezek suggested

Comment: At first I thought that is his intention. But it doesnt make any sense. Edited. Thanks